# Best search match

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement the most relevant search result for a website.

Below is how I want it to look like:

If someone types in "Beauty" it should first search if any account username has the handle "@beauty" and display that one first, then the rest of the accounts that match the criteria below:

- Matching keyword
- Keyword in handle or account name
- Keyword in account's bio

The code I am currently using:

```
$searchset = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, rtrim($_GET['search']));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '%".$searchset."%' OR keywords LIKE '%".$searchset."%' OR bio LIKE '%".$searchset."%')";
```

I have been reading on methods using weighted search or mysql `MATCH()`, but I couldn't figure out the best code to achieve my required results.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Get rid of that, use prepared statements and append % to each side of the variables, then put in there. Safer.

Comment: @miken32 I want it to first search if any accounts have the username and display that one first, then the rest of the accounts that match the criteria I mentioned above.

Comment: @clearshot66 may you kindly provide a code example? Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth considering using a search engine like ElasticSearch because ranking is much harder than just matching and MySQL might not be as good as a proper search engine in ranking and weighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `ORDER BY` should do the job:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '%".$searchset."%' OR keywords LIKE '%".$searchset."%' OR bio LIKE '%".$searchset."%') ORDER BY '$searchset' != username";
```

You should look into prepared statements, and I recommend using PDO instead of mysqli. The syntax is much more modern and there are many shortcuts and convenience methods available.

Comment: He wants weighted search in the order specified, this will just prioritize an exact match for the username but do nothing for the other criteria

Comment: @msg question asks for "search if any accounts have the handle "@beauty" and display that one first, then the rest of the accounts"

Comment: @miken32 would it not be ORDER BY '$searchset' = username"
or am i confused?

Comment: @Amr If you think of the boolean result as a number, true is 1 and false is 0. The false results would come first so we search for records that don't match.

Comment: @miken32 but I want to display all the accounts matching the username first, then display the rest of the accounts according to matching keyword, bio, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what this does